# Modal not open when in normal window

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, bootstrap-modal

Here I am using the `croppie.js` to upload an `image` for user. All are working perfectly but the problem is, the modal is only open when it is in `debug` window. When it is closed, the `modal` doesn't open.

Here is the `HTML`.

```
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
               <div id="user_data">

               </div>
            </div>  
         </div>

        <!-- crop image model  -->
        <div id="uploadimageModal" class="modal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Upload & Crop Image</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-8 text-center">
                                <div id="image_demo" style="width:350px; margin-top:30px"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4" style="padding-top:30px;">
                                <br />
                                <br />
                                <br />
                                <button class="btn btn-success crop_image">Crop & Upload Image</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Below is the `Ajax` query

```
            load_data();
            function load_data() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "adminquery/fetch/fetch.php", // Url to which the request is send
                    type: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method

                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#user_data').html(data);

                    }

                });

            }

            // crop image
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $image_crop = $('#image_demo').croppie({
                    enableExif: true,
                    viewport: {
                        width: 150,
                        height: 150,
                        type: 'square' //circle
                    },
                    boundary: {
                        width: 300,
                        height: 300
                    }

                });

                $('#upload_image').on('change', function () {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (event) {
                        $image_crop.croppie('bind', {
                            url: event.target.result
                        }).then(function () {
                            console.log('jQuery bind complete');
                        });
                    }
                    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
                    $('#uploadimageModal').modal('show');
                });

                $('.crop_image').click(function (event) {
                    $image_crop.croppie('result', {
                        type: 'canvas',
                        size: 'viewport'
                    }).then(function (response) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "profile/profilepic.php",
                            type: "POST",
                            data: { "image": response },
                            success: function (data) {
                                $('#uploadimageModal').modal('hide');
                                $('#uploaded_image').html(data);

                                load_data();

                            }
                        });
                    })

                });
            });
```

I am very grateful if someone help me. Thanks in advance.